# Looping over dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

So I have 4 dataframes that I am attempting to loop over.

I have created a list using the following code :

`list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]`

After that I would like to write them to an SQL Server using :

`for i in list:
    i.to_sql(i,engine)`

However this leads to the following error

> 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any suggestions what I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `SQL table` name in the first parameter

**Ex:**

```
l = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

for i in l:
    i.to_sql('TABLE_NAME',con=engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the itertuples method in pandas:

```
for i in dataframeList.itertuples():
    print i
```